# Return string of SQL one to many values

Tags: t-sql

I have a table: Task, and another TaskHistory

1 Task -> Many Task Histories

TaskHistory has a field named 'Comment'.

I would like to from SQL return a string of all of the Task History Comments for whatever TaskId I pass in.

Example:
GetTaskHistory(@TaskId)

Returns:
'Comment: some comment \r\n Comment: another comment \r\n\ Comment: yet another'

I am wondering if returning this from SQL would be faster than a recordset that I loop through in my application to build a string.

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, however I would recommend keeping the formatting in the application and simple return the data from SQL. That is however my opinion on how applications should be separated.

```
SELECT Comment
FROM TaskHistory
WHERE TaskID = 1
```

To concatenate column results into a string you can do something like:

```
DECLARE @HistoryComments nvarchar(MAX) 

SELECT @HistoryComments = COALESCE(@HistoryComments + ' \r\n ', '') + Comment
FROM FROM TaskHistory
WHERE TaskID = 1

SELECT TaskHistorys = @HistoryComments
```